# Why would adding a programmatically rendered panel break ajax beahvior for a declared Panel?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following frontend code using primefaces

```
    <p:panel binding="#{widgetBean.panel}"/>

    <p:panel header="Widget 2" id="declaredPanel" style="height:300px; width:300px">
        <p:droppable tolerance="touch" scope="widgetDrop" activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" >
            <p:ajax listener="#{widgetBean.widgetDropped}" ></p:ajax>
        </p:droppable>
    </p:panel>
```

with this for the backend bean:

```
public Panel getPanel(){
    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.setHeader("test");
    p.setId("programmaticPanel");
    p.setStyle("height:300px; width:300px");
    Droppable d = new Droppable();
    d.setDatasource("availableWidgets");
    d.setTolerance("touch");
    d.setScope("widgetDrop");
    d.setActiveStyleClass("ui-state-highlight");

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExpressionFactory ef = fc.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    MethodExpression onDropExpr = ef.createMethodExpression(
       fc.getELContext(), "#{widgetBean.widgetDropped}", null, new Class[] {     DragDropEvent.class });

    AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = new AjaxBehavior();
    ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(onDropExpr));

    d.addClientBehavior("drop", ajaxBehavior);

    p.getChildren().add(d);
    return p;
  }
  public void widgetDropped(DragDropEvent ddEvent) {
    System.out.println("DROP EXECUTED ON SERVER");
  }
```

The weirdest thing happens. If I use both ways of rendering the Panel in the UI my ajax listener never gets called.  If I remove the Panel that uses a binding my drop listener gets executed.  On top of that I can return an just a plain jane panel with no droppable children and the declarative panel still will not fire a listener. However the opposite is not true. If I remove the declarative panel the programmticaly bound one still never fires the listener.  Really I have two problems:
1.) rendering a programmatic panel breaks the drop listener event on the declarative Panel
2.) In any scenario the drop listener never gets called for the programmatic Panel.

I'm using Primefaces 3.2 and running on Glassfish 3.1.1 I would LOVE any help at this point. I've researched this problem and found others complain about issues binding ajaxbehaviors programmtically, notably: [Linky link](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13144) This seemed to have solved the issue for some...not the case for me. Thanks!